# Azure File Share - Prevent Consumer Access During StartCopyAsync

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I am attempting to copy a file to Azure File Share via .Net Storage client (v12) for an integration.

The plan is copy file from Azure Storage to Azure File Share in the same account. That works fine.

I am using the StartCopyAsync method and it works as expected during testing.

However, for the live integration, the consumer is reading the file during the copy operation with zero bytes. The consumer then deletes the file. However, they have accessed and copied deleted the file before it was complete. Is there anything I can do to prevent access to the file during copy operation?

They have the file share mounted an SMB share and monitored and BizTalk is just seeing the file instantly.

Options looked at:

1. Uploading file and renaming - Azure File Share doesn't seem to support rename?
2. Uploading Marked ReadOnly and Hidden. SMB doesn't care if the file is ReadOnly and the other part of integration can't change to ignore hidden files
3. Take File Lease - To prevent deletion - still has the problem of client reading the empty file as soon as it hits the file share

Something else?

Comment: Azure Storage Files support [`NTFS attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file#file-system-attributes). What you can do is set appropriate attributes on the file (probably `ReadOnly` and `Hidden`) so that the consumer is not able to see the file and cannot delete it while you're copying the file. Will something like this work for you?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yeah I am pretty sure that BizTalk could be told to not look at hidden files. Can I then just toggle it back to visible. That was what I was hoping to do

Comment: Yes. You can change the properties of the file at any time.

Comment: @GauravMantri  so the file doesn't exist at StartCopyAsync can I set those properties at the same time as StartCopyAsync

Comment: Yes. If you look at the [`REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-file#request-headers), you should be able to specify the attributes in request header. Please check the description for `x-ms-file-attributes` header.

Comment: @GauravMantri  Setting NTFS ReadOnly doesn't prevent them from deleting it via SMB.  They are having trouble changing the integration at their end. Is there any way to prevent them from being able to delete it until I release it. I looked at lease - and file permissions but wasn't sure if that was possible. I tried issuing a lease and using that in the CreateAsync or StartCopyAsync and I didn't seem to be able to do it with a non existing file

Comment: Hmmm...What happens when you set the attribute as "Hidden"?

Comment: I don't think lease would work considering the file does not exist yet.

Comment: @GauravMantri Same issue have set it hidden, offline, readonly and they see it and take it.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yeah lease doesn't. I tried to do it at ShareClient level as well but that didn't work either

Comment: Just curious, where are you running your code for copying the file? I am assuming you're copying from blob storage to a file share. Right?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes. Azure function that copies Blob from same storage account fileShareFileClient.StartCopy(blobSasUri) or fileShareFileClient.StartCopyAsync(blobSasUri)

Comment: Thanks. One idea (a whacky one :)) could be to actually use an Azure VM and mount the file share there. Then download the blob from blob storage and create a file in that file share using `System.IO`. I believe that way you can have an exclusive lock on the file while it is being created in the file share. I am suggesting Azure VM because you can't mount a File Share in an Azure Function (or WebApp for that matter).

Comment: @GauravMantri Yeah I noticed I could make it work by just renaming the file in the mounted share. That seems a rather crazy way to have to do it. I will try to get the integration changed. I just expected me to be able to copy a blob before it was accessible to anyone else

Comment: @GauravMantri Any idea if I am correct in understanding that if I take a lease on the shareClient as a whole then nothing in that share can be deleted until the lease is released? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-share Per remarks "A lease on a file share provides exclusive delete access to the file share. "

Comment: Based on my understanding, No. You will still be able to delete the files inside a share even if the file share is leased. Leasing a share will protect from deleting that share.